# Compare datetime value in stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I am having trouble writing SQL Server queries/procedures with `DateTime` format in the tables.

My application runs on a standard ASP.NET MVC4 stack with SQL Server.

My table `Bookings` has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bookings] 
(
    [BookingId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ShowId]    INT NOT NULL,
    [RowId]     INT NULL,
    [Username]  VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [PaymentId] INT NULL,
    [ShowDate]  DATETIME NULL,
    .....
    ....    
);
```

I have written two stored procedures where I am trying to compare table column `ShowDate` with different date parameters declared in stored procedure.

Procedure #1:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBookingsByDate]
    @venueid int,
    @fromdate datetime,
    @todate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        City, Title, ScreenTitle, ShowDate,
        SUM([Qty]) AS Quantity, 
        SUM([Charges]) AS TotalAmount, 
        SUM([OtherCharges]) AS OtherCharges
    FROM 
        ShowBookings
    WHERE 
        Venueid = @venueid 
        AND ShowDate BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate
    GROUP BY 
        ScreenId, ShowDate, Venueid, Title, ScreenTitle, City
END
```

Procedure #2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAudienceReportsHistory]
    @state varchar,
    @city varchar,
    @theaterName varchar,
    @showdate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        b.BookingId, b.MobileNo, b.SeatNumbers, b.EmailId,
        sc.ScreenTitle, sh.ShowTime, a.Title, 
        b.Username, b.SMSStatus 
    FROM 
        Bookings b 
    JOIN
        Shows sh ON b.ShowId = sh.Id
    JOIN 
        Venues AS v ON sh.Venue_Id = v.Id
    JOIN 
        Artifacts a ON sh.Artifact_Id = a.Id
    JOIN
        Screens AS sc ON sh.Screen_ScreenId = sc.ScreenId
    WHERE
        b.ShowDate = @showdate 
        AND b.IsBooked = 'true' 
        AND b.TimeSolt = '0' 
        AND v.Title = @theaterName 
        AND v.City = @city
END
```

As you can see procedure #1 takes two datetime parameters, `fromdate` and `todate`. The second procedure takes only one datetime parameter `showdate`.

Procedure #1 returns the correct set of results, however procedure #2 returns no results at all. But I have crosschecked in the tables that I have proper data which should be returned for the Proc2 query. There seems to be some DateTime format mismatch.

I'm sending datetime parameters to the queries in "yyyy-mm-dd" format (eg: 2017-05-30). Inside the table the `ShowDate` column is stored in "dd-mm-yyyy" (eg: 30-05-2017) format.

I have tried sending the parameter in different date formats but I'm not getting any results for Proc2. Kindly help me in solving this. Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: you are missing time component - you need to cast b.ShowDate to Date if @showdate is something like '2017-06-01 00:00:00:00000'

Comment: Please post some of your actual date/time entries.  My guess would be you have dates with a time element, so when you search for a range they are found, but an exact date would only match dates where the time part is 00:00

Comment: In `Proc1`, the query is on a single table. In `Proc2`, the query is on multiple tables having joins. It could be that on or more of the joins fails (i.e. there is no matching data). Have you specifically investigated this?

Comment: `DATETIME` always contains **both** date **and** time and a comparison with an equality operator `=` must match **both parts** exactly. If you're on SQL Server 2008, and you're interested *only* in the date - time is irrevelant - then I'd strongly suggest to use `DATE` as datatype, instead of `DATETIME` - `DATE` **only** stores the date without any time, so the comparison will really be on the day - not on some millisecond in the day....

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use! Otherwise, your stored procedure parameters (`@state`, `@city`, `@theatername`) suddenly end up being **exactly ONE character** long - which is typically *not* what you expect or want - **define a length** - always.

Comment: "*dd-mm-yyyy*" vs "*yyyy-mm-dd*" is no issue here, as both are typed `datetime`. It would be an issue if either/both were one of the four `char`-based types. I like to think that `datetime` or any similar type is stored internally as an integer, for most purposes that thought works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to note that datetime includes time so when you equate that to a datetime field it will never be equal due to time difference... what you can do is cast both dates... meanwhile between captures time within the date

```
cast(showdate as date) = cast(@showdate as date)
```

or DateDIFF

```
datediff(day,@showdate,showdate) = 0
```

Comment: He could also make use of `DATEDIFF`.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to convert Date Proper Formate like this

```
CONVERT(date, b.ShowDate) = CONVERT(date,@showdate )
```